# SOAP Body ID missing or how to set using WCF

Tags: wcf, soap, proxy, signature

I am using WCF and Proxy class to communicate with a Government web service. The web service expects the body of the message to be signed as well as WS-*
I use the following code

```
proxy.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;
```

The Signature Element generated contains `<Reference URI="#_0">` However the Body Tag has no ID !

Any pointers on how to set this would be most helpful.

Comment: Please post your WCF configuration. In particular, I want to see the rest of your binding.